# How do I split a sentence into several phrases?

Tags: python

I want to split a sentence into several meaningful part, for example:
I have an input from user:`Samsung phone case` , I want to split in to a list:[`Samsung phone`, `phone case`,`Samsung phone case`], that means `Samsung phone` is a valid object, `phone case` is another valid object, `Samsung phone case` also is a valid object, how to do this with python?

The moderator said I need to add some debug details, so let me explain it a little more, what I need is to analysis the input from a user, like split/combination, another example:
a user input :`case of Samsung phone`, the result I need is:[`case of Samsung`, `case of Samsung phone`, `Samsung phone`], it's not a sample split and combination, cuz `case of` is not what I need, I tried nltk lib, it can split in to every word, but doesn't have a combination.

So the key point is after the combination, the phrase/word should be meaningful like the example above => every of [`case of Samsung`, `case of Samsung phone`, `Samsung phone`] is meaningful, but `case of` is not meaningful(not a valid object).

I don't know if there's an AI lib can help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you want a split, but rather combinations (or some kind of power set).
Splitting is a necessary intermediate though:

```
s = 'Samsung phone case'

from itertools import combinations, chain

l = s.split()
list(chain(*(map(' '.join, combinations(l, r=n)) for n in range(2,len(l)+1))))
```

output:

```
['Samsung phone', 'Samsung case', 'phone case', 'Samsung phone case']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I added more details, so this sample combination is not what I need, cuz I need to make sure every phrase/word is meaningful, like my example in my added details.

Comment: Whether a sentence is meaningful or not is subjective. Or at least this is not trivial, and in any case difficult to generalize. You should first come up with rules to determine the validity of your sentences, then you can try to code something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *indexing* if you know the input string. For example:

```
txt = "Samsung phone case"

x = txt[0:13]
y = txt[8:19]

new_txt = [x, y, txt]

print(new_txt)
```

The output will be:

```
>>> ['Samsung phone', 'phone case', 'Samsung phone case']
```

Alternatively, you can use Regular Expressions, such as:

```
import re
txt = ['Samsung phone case']
x = re.search('(.*?) (case)', txt).group(1)
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for reply! For the first think, I don't know the index of the string. For the second, I don't know what user will input, maybe next time the input is 'case of iphone 6' , so Reg also cannot help!

Comment: You can use RegEx anyway, for example with `re.findall('(.*?) , txt, 0)` you get everything between spaces and combine them in a string in the order you desire. There are also other valid solutions using other RegEx commands.